# XPATH select distinct values

Tags: xml, xpath, distinct

I would like to select pages when one of two attributes (width or height) are distinct.

Here is my XML:

```
<pages>
    <page id="page0001" height="1000" width="960"></page>
    <page id="page4931" height="1000" width="960"></page>
    <page id="page6342" height="1000" width="961"></page>
    <page id="page7995" height="1001" width="961"></page>
    <page id="page4461" height="1001" width="960"></page>
    <page id="page4690" height="1001" width="960"></page>
    <page id="page9001" height="1001" width="961"></page>
</pages>
```

Here my select

```
<xsl:for-each select="/prototype/pages/page[@width != (preceding-sibling::*/@width) or @height != (preceding-sibling::*/@height) or position() = 1]">
    <div class="{@width}x{@height} {@id}"></div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Here the result:

```
<div class="960x1000 page0001"></div>
<div class="961x1000 page6342"></div>
<div class="961x1001 page7995"></div>
<div class="960x1001 page4461"></div>
<div class="960x1001 page4690"></div>
<div class="961x1001 page9001"></div>
```

What I expect to have

```
<div class="960x1000 page0001"></div>
<div class="961x1000 page6342"></div>
<div class="961x1001 page7995"></div>
<div class="960x1001 page4461"></div>
```

I know that my select is incorrect and I understand why. Is there any possibility to modify it in order to get the right result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that comparison operators such as `=` and `!=` in XPath are implicitly *existentially quantified*, in other words

```
@width != preceding-sibling::*/@width
```

checks whether there is *any* preceding sibling whose width is different from mine.  What you actually want in this case is that the *combination* of width and height for this node is different from the combination of width and height for any of its predecessors.  You could do this with a `for-each` over all pages and a test within the body of the `for-each`

```
<xsl:for-each select="/prototype/pages/page">
    <xsl:variable name="myWidth" select="@width" />
    <xsl:variable name="myHeight" select="@height" />
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[@height=$myHeight][@width=$myWidth])">
        <div class="{@width}x{@height} {@id}"></div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively you can treat it as a grouping problem - group the `page` elements by their width and height, and output one div per group.  In XSLT 2.0 this could be

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/prototype/pages/page"
      group-by="concat(@width, 'x', @height)">
    <div class="{current-grouping-key()} {@id}" />
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In 1.0 you can get the same effect using the *Muenchian grouping* method (there are many other questions you can find with the search function that explain it well so I won't repeat it again here).

Comment: Thanks, I was not really able to formulate what is wrong in my select. Actually I wanted save some iterations by using a single select. It seams to be too complicated for xpath :p

Comment: @charles I doubt it really "saves" anything since the processor will have to inspect all the `page` elements in turn to decide which ones match the predicate.  It's just the difference between an explicit `if` and the implicit one that the predicate will compile into.

Comment: @charles The issue is that a single select to do this would essentially have to say `page[not(preceding-sibling::*[ ... ])]` with two levels of predicates, and there's no way in XPath 1.0 for the inner predicate to reference the node that the outer predicate is currently looking at.  In 2.0 you can use a `some $x in preceding-sibling::* satisfies ...` construct, but if you're in XSLT 2.0 then you might as well use `for-each-group` anyway.